# Sorting an array by two values using compareTo

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I am trying to sort an array using compareTo. 
This is what i have now:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Episode other) {
    return Integer.compare(episodeNummer, other.episodeNummer);
}
```

I am now sorting only by episodenumber, but I am trying to also sort the list by season.

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.

Comment: May be easier using `Arrays.sort(episodes, Comparator.comparingInt(Episode::getEpisodeNummer).thenComparing(Episode::getEpisodeTitle));`